# Replace underscores in unknown subdomains with dashes in an nginx redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx

I've got URLs coming in that look like this:

```
https://some_sub_domain.whatever.com
```

That need to be redirected to:

```
https://some-sub-domain.whatever.com
```

I don't know what the subdomains will be (they're usernames).

While I need to replace underscores for the subdomain, I need to leave other underscores in-tact:

```
https://some_sub_domain.whatever.com/hey_there_underscore
```

Should redirect to:

```
https://some-sub-domain.whatever.com/hey_there_underscore
```

Comment: Would http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html help? Standard rewrites won't be as flexible.

Comment: This might give you some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12339977

Comment: You _should_ not rewrite underscores in host names. You _should_ prevent underscores from entering the hostname. And [here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-someone-have-a-subdomain-with-an-underscore-in-it)

Comment: Well, Django throws a "SuspiciousOperation" error when hostnames with underscores are used, so I wanted to intercept them before it hits the application stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to rewrite via lua:

```
location / {
  rewrite_by_lua '
  if string.find(ngx.var.host, "_") then
    local newHost, n = ngx.re.gsub(ngx.var.host, "_", "-")
    ngx.redirect(ngx.var.scheme .. "://" .. newHost .. ngx.var.uri)
  end
  ';
  proxy_pass       http://my_backend;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no '.'s in the username, you can use regular expressions:

```
(https?://)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\..*)
```

And using the second grouping call a simple replace. Doing this with the perl module favoretti suggested should work fine, but I frankly don't have enough experience with nginx or the perl module to do it.